# Google Analytics High Session Rate vs. Low Avg. Session Duration

Tags: session, google-analytics, traffic, visitor-pattern

My department has installed google analytics on our companies website and none of us are exactly experts on understanding why the data is the way it is.

Anyways, our company is fairly large, but I wouldn't say we are exactly a well known company. We provide internet and Video on Demand to Hotels worldwide. Anyways, as of right now, since I have installed our code last month, we have a total session number of over 78,000. Our average session duration is only 24 seconds, with an average page view per visitor at 1.18 and a bounce rate of 91%.

I don't doubt the session average time. Me and my co-workers are just a little confused as to how with that many visitors, we are consistently across the board getting such a fairly small session duration and a high bounce rate. Could visitors possibly just come to our website, look for our phone number and than leave the site? I'm just trying to find a way to reduce the bounce rate and hopefully increase the session duration average. Or is it possible to add a filter that will exclude visits to the site that are less than 30 seconds, or something like that? I apologize for asking such fairly basic questions I'm sure. I am trying to get up to speed and familiarize myself with how this all works. Just thought I'd maybe ask and see if I am missing something important. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell why your metrics are so low across the board. Your referral traffic could be to blame here - possibly bad ad copy from adwords or bing, which is making users think they're going to a different page.  You can always create a filter by the acquisition, and where the clicks and sessions are coming from. From there it'll be easier to see which source of traffic is to blame, and also how you can improve your site overall for traffic optimization and user friendliness. For more info, reach us at RLCppc.com on the matter. hope that answers your question